# Ошибка 500 на хостинге

Tags: хостинг, http-status-code-500

Пытаюсь закинуть сайт на бесплатный хостинг 000webhost.
Выдаёт такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоли:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
```

Пробовал править файл htaccess - не помогло. Может есть у кого идеи?
Файл htaccess:

```
# HTID:6559460: DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW
php_value display_errors 1
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE HTID:6559460:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Читайте логи, они должны быть где-то у хостинга

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем у тебя проблема скорее всего в хостинге, либо ты не подключил BD 
Либо скрипт,

Попробуй добавить

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

Comment: Также попробуй сменить версию Php